# REST Service - Whitelisting

Tags: rest-api, webservices, ip

I'm leverging a service from one of our internal system through a REST webservice callout.
The system have to be configured for white listing the IP ranges.

Following are the IP ranges I have for the North America region.
[image]

I'm looking for the Port details also. I don't find it in SF documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce uses standard ports by default. This would be port 80 for HTTP (mostly unused) and port 443 for HTTPS (SSL/TLS). You can use other ports for outbound calls (e.g. from a Visualforce page), so you'd have to determine if you're using non-standard ports for callouts.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox

Comment: @sfdcfox can we disable port 80 for login and also for callouts and webservices?

Comment: @oabarca TLS is required for all incoming traffic, period. Outbound TLS security is controlled by administrators/developers. In that sense, you can decide which services, if any, allow HTTP-only connections.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the info. During our security scan we noticed that port 80 was opened. There is a redirect to https, but we would like to know if we can close port 80 altogether. Perhaps by making use of a custom domain?

Comment: @oabarca Not for Salesforce. They control the service and its functionality.